# Why does Ruriko get angry when she's called as "Rurippe"?

Tags: japanese-language, gate-keepers

Why does Ruriko get angry whenever Shun calls her as "Rurippe" when according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_Keepers#Characters),

> 'Rurippe' holds no real meaning except that Shun relates it to her
>   childhood appearance as a sniveler (or one who always has a runny
>   nose).

How does Shun relate this nickname to Ruriko as a sniveler? Is it because of how it is written in kanji or how the nickname is pronounced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Japanese wikipedia article for the series](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA#.E7.99.BB.E5.A0.B4.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9):

> In the anime, Shun called her "the sniffling Rurippe" (鼻たれのルリっぺ) during their
>   childhood which has become a sort of trauma for her.

So I don't think it's about the name Rurippe itself (which is written in all kana by the way, no kanji) but how Shun used it in the past. In the past, he called her "the sniffling Rurippe" so now whenever he just calls her "Rurippe" it reminds her of the original full name which included "sniffling".